# Вывести индексы всех пробелов строки

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Нужно вывести индексы всех пробелов и отдельно обработать конец строки. Без обработки конца строки, как можно реализовать? (только начинающий, с алгоритмом проблемы)
Пример: `green  parrot`, должен выдавать 5 6 13. При работе данного кода, выдает 5 6
Имеется код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string query;
    getline(cin, query);

    for (int i = 0; i <= query.size(); ++i) {
        if (query[i] == ' ') {
            cout << i << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что с текущим кодом не так? Какие ошибки или неправильный вывод получаете? Укажите это в вопросе с помощью кнопки править

Comment: как обработать конец строки?

Comment: *"Без обработки конца строки, как можно реализовать"* Вот эту часть не понял. Это вас преподаватель с такой формулировкой завернул? Если да, то скорее всего от вас хотят заменить `<=` на `<` - последний символ всегда `\0`, его нет смысла проверять.

Comment: @dIm0n Конкретизировал описание

Comment: @HolyBlackCat он должен тоже его посчитать

Comment: @azlov должен посчитать его тоже и вывести

Comment: @yusup.abzui отформатируйте пример так же, как и код, потому что лишние пробелы потерялись и непонятно, почему ответ должен быть таким

Comment: @dIm0n исправил

Comment: @yusup.abzui так почему 13 должно быть? Там же пробелы на 5 и 6 позициях

Comment: @yusup.abzu, видимо вы не ввели последний пробел, поэтому получили только 5 и 6

Comment: @dlm0n именно, что нету и должно быть 13

Comment: @azlov в примере которым мне дали его нету, видимо как-то должен посчитать что конец строки, прибавить и вывести

Comment: Дано условие: Пройдитесь по строке и выведите индексы всех пробелов. Отдельно обработайте конец строки: на нём всегда кончается какое-либо слово.

Answer (score 3):

Так?

```
for (int i = 0; i <= query.size(); ++i) {
        if (i == query.size()  ||  query[i] == ' ') {
            cout << i << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Условия стоит местами поменять

Comment: @MBo То есть, он проверят, если размер одинаковый с i или стоит пробел?

Comment: Если i достигло конца строки или пробел

Comment: @dIm0n Почему ?

Comment: @MBo скорее всего, при включенных оптимизациях разницы не будет, но вообще первое условие выполняется только 1 раз за строку, а второе может много раз, поэтому при проходе пробельной строки в текущем варианте будет (N-1)*2 + 1 проверок, а с перевёрнутыми условиями — N-1 + 2

Comment: @dIm0n OK. Привык не вылезать за конец строки.

Comment: @yusup.abzui поставьте галку слева от ответа

Comment: Пытался, но репутации не хватает, как наберу закину :)

Comment: @yusup.abzui Репутации не хватает для плюсования, а для приёма ответа она не нужна

Comment: `i == query.size()` в цикле не нужна. Цикл сократить на одну итерацию, после цикла написать размер строки отдельным выводом.

Answer (score 1):

Ну можно повыпендироваться и написать лямбду с мьютбл и бешать по ней - почему пишу так - более унифицирвоанно чем просто for но тащить больше хедеров... ждем модули

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
 
int main() {
  std::string line {"a test line"};
  auto f{[i{0}](unsigned char ch) mutable {if (std::isspace(ch)) {std::cout << i << std::endl;} i++;}};
  std::for_each(std::begin(line), std::end(line), f);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот ещё вариант:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string query;
    getline(cin, query);

    size_t pos = query.find(' ');         // Находим первый пробел и сохраняем его индекс
    while (pos != string::npos)           // Если пробел в строке есть
    {
        cout << pos << '\t';              // Выводим индекс
        pos = query.find(' ', pos + 1);   // Ищем следующий пробел
    }
    cout << query.size() << endl;         // А вот и конец строки

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Так себе вариант - у вас в двух местах вызывается find, хотя можно обойтись одним

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Поместить вызов `find` в условие `while`? Вы об этом?

Comment: в while не получится, а вот в do while - можно. Но и это так себе - я бы сделал через regex